# Cypress build error in Azure pipeline: Cannot find module '@cypress/code-coverage/task'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress

Here is my config:

```
// cypress/plugins/index.js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
  //require('@bahmutov/cypress-extends')(on, config);
  return config
}
```

I am getting an ERROR when trying to run cypress in a Azure pipeline script (within a cypress/included container).  This error doesn't occur when I run on my local.

```
The function exported by the plugins file threw an error.

We invoked the function exported by `/root/e2e/cypress/plugins/index.js`, but it threw an error.

 Error: Cannot find module '@cypress/code-coverage/task'
Require stack:
- /root/e2e/cypress/plugins/index.js
- /root/.cache/Cypress/9.1.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js
```

The only unusual thing I am doing is this:

```
// cypress/config/cypress.local.json
{
  "extends": "../../cypress.json",
  "baseUrl": "https://localhost:4200"
}
```

And a normal cypress.json config:

```
// /cypress.json
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
  "proxyUrl": "",
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,
  "video" : false,
  "screenshotOnRunFailure" : true,
  "experimentalStudio": true,
  "projectId": "seixri",
  "trashAssetsBeforeRuns" : true,
  "videoUploadOnPasses" : false,
  "retries": {
    "runMode": 0,
    "openMode": 0
  },
  "viewportWidth": 1000,
  "viewportHeight": 1200
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here might be that Cypress does not support extending the configuration file in the way you did, as also stated here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/18/extending-the-cypress-config-file/

In my opinion there are two suitable solution approaches:

**1. Approach: Use separate configuration files (my recommendation)**

As extending an existing configuration file does not work, I would recommend having separate configuration files, e.g. one for local usage and one for the execution in Azure pipelines. You could then simple add two separate commands in your `package.json` like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "cy:ci": "cypress run --config-file cypress/cypress.json",
    "cy:local": "cypress run --config-file cypress/cypress.local.json"
  },
```

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration

**2. Approach: Set configuration options in your tests**

Cypress gives you the option to overwrite configurations directly in your tests. For example, if you have configured the following in `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "viewportWidth": 1280,
  "viewportHeight": 720
}
```

You can change the *viewportWidth* in your test like:

```
Cypress.config('viewportWidth', 800)
```

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Syntax

Comment: yeah, it turns out the extending config was causing part of the problem.